# Why can I change dict values by referencing keys but not the values themselves?

Tags: python

Here, is my code:

```
# Write your add_ten function here:
def add_ten(dic):
  for key, val in dic.items():
    dic[key] += 10
  return dic
# Uncomment these function calls to test your  function:
print(add_ten({1:5, 2:2, 3:3}))
# should print {1:15, 2:12, 3:13}
#print(add_ten({10:1, 100:2, 1000:3}))
# should print {10:11, 100:12, 1000:13}
```

This works, however initially I did:

```
for val in dick.values():
    val += 10
```

Using visualizer, this added 10 to the value, but the value was not saved. Why?

Comment: Because some objects are mutable while others are immutable. In your case, integers are not mutable, so the content of the dct can only be changed by assignment - and you want to assign the new value to the dict and not to some other variable name, pointing to the same immutable object.

Comment: Can you please change your dictionaries name?

Comment: Because `val` is simply a temp variable which will be overwritten during the next loop iteration. You don't want to change `val` but the value in the dictionary. That's why your solution does not work.

Comment: `val += 10` is short for `val = val.__iadd__(10)`. Since `int.__iadd__` is not implemented, Python falls back to `val = val.__add__(10)`. As a result, you are only assigning a new value to the name `val`, rather than mutating the object stored in the `dict` that `val` refers to.

Answer (score 2):

In this loop:

```
for val in dick.values():
    val += 10
```

`val` is not a reference to a mutable value in the dictionary. `val += 10` is implemented as `val = val + 10` -- you are reassigning the local variable `val` rather than modifying the original dictionary value that it was initialized with.